# How to select distinct data from database on the bases of catagories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in database named `posts` in which there are five columns name

```
id, title , author , cata , content
```

*`cata` means categories

I want to fetch 10 rows of data of different categories
like

```
select * from `posts` by distinct cata
```

Something like.

e.g.
I want this result

```
1.this is gaming posts author(Mauk) cata(Gaming) content......
2.this is glossary posts author(Mauk) cata(glossary) content......
3.this is shoes posts author(Mauk) cata(shoes) content......
4.this is garments posts author(Mauk) cata(garments) content......
5.this is you tube posts author(Mauk) cata(YouTube ) content......
6.this is blogging posts author(Mauk) cata(blogging ) content......
7.this is editing posts author(Mauk) cata(editing) content......
8.this is electronics posts author(Mauk) cata(electronics) content......
9.this is programming posts author(Mauk) cata(programming ) content......
10.this is news posts author(Mauk) cata(news) content......
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can do:

```
select p.*
from posts p
order by row_number() over (partition by cata order by id)
limit 10;
```

In earlier versions, you can get the most recent post for each category by doing:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.id = (select max(p2.id)
              from posts p2 
              where p2.cata = p.cata
             )
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check the following query

```
select distinct cata, id, title, autho, content from posts LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top 10` and concatenating the value selected as below

```
Select Top 10 'this is gaming posts ' + author + '   ' +  cata + ' your content...'  from 
 posts order by id ;
```